# why i get System.IndexOutOfRangeException: EmpPassword

Tags: asp.net

```
 myreader = obj.ExecuteReader 
 If myreader.Read Then 
    Session.Item("emp_id") = myreader("emp_id")
    Session.Item("Email") = myreader("e_mail")
    Session.Item("password") = myreader("EmpPassword") 
 ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "123456" Then 
     Response.Redirect("home.aspx")
 Else 
     Response.Redirect("personal.aspx") 
 End If
```

Comment: Show the SELECT statement used to extract this data.

Comment: this the statement (select [E_mail] from personaldetails where [E_mail] =@E_mail and EmpPassword =@EmpPassword)

Comment: If you don't list your EmpPassword field between the SELECT you cannot read it back from the reader. Also emp_id seems to be missing, same error

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated when you try to read a field from the reader that is not present in the SELECT field list of your query. So, if you want to read the EmpPassword value you need to change your query to

```
Dim query = "SELECT emp_id, E_mail, EmpPassword from personaldetails " & _
            "where [E_mail] =@E_mail and EmpPassword =@EmpPassword"
Dim obj = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
.... add the parameters....
myreader = obj.ExecuteReader 
.......
```

However, you already know the password and the email value because you need to set the parameters required by the where clause, so you could avoid to read them from the reader and add the fields to the select list.

Answer (score 0):

Select statement should include all fields that you want to retrieve -

```
SELECT  emp_id, [E_mail], EmpPassword
FROM    personaldetails
WHERE   [E_mail] = @E_mail
        AND EmpPassword = @EmpPassword
```

**- OR -**

Since you already know **e_mail** and **EmpPassword**, you can select **emp_id** only,  and assign **e_mail** and **EmpPassword** from **original** values  -

```
select [emp_id] from personaldetails 
where [E_mail] =@E_mail and EmpPassword =@EmpPassword

Session.Item("emp_id") = myreader("emp_id")
Session.Item("Email") = e_mail
Session.Item("password") = EmpPassword
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm glad that you solved the problem. If this answered your question, please mark it as Answer. It'll help others who look for the same answer.